# json with array

Tags: python, json

I am trying to create a `dict` like this:

```
{
  "Name": "string",
  "Info": [
    {
      "MainID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "Values": [
        {
          "IndvidualID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
          "Result": "string"
        },
        {
          "IndvidualID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
          "Result": "string"
        }
    ] 
    }
  ]
}
```

Where the `Values` section has 100+ things inside of it. I put 2 as an example.

Unsure how to build this dynamically. Code I have attempted so far:

```
count = 0
with open('myTextFile.txt') as f:
        line = f.readline()
        line = line.rstrip()
        myValues[count]["IndvidualID"] = count
        myValues[count]["Result"] = line
        count = count +1

data = {"Name": "Demo",
       "Info": [{
          "MainID":TEST_SUITE_ID,
          "Values":myValues
       }}
```

This does not work however. Due to "Key Error 0" it says. Works if I do it like  `myValues[count]= count` but as soon as I add the extra layer it breaks  `myValues[count]["IndvidualID"] = count`.   I see some example of setting a list in there, but I need like a List (Values) with multiple things inside (ID and Result). Have tried a few things with no luck. Anyone have a simple way to do this in python?

```
Full traceback:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testExtractor.py", line 28, in <module>
    myValues[count]["IndvidualID"] = count
KeyError: 0
```

Comment: Please update your question with the reason that *'This does not work however`*.

Comment: Please provide the contents of `myTextFile.txt`, or more specifically, the contents it would need to have in order to produce the json data in your first code block.

Comment: @kevin Its just text lines. Such as: Apple, another apple, another another apple (where comma is new line, hard to type comment.

Comment: I imagine from the code you have posted you are getting an error. You refer to `myValues` without defining it. Please update your question with the full Traceback of the error you are seeing.

Comment: If your file contains only "apple" and "another apple", etc, then what does that have to do with the output you want? I don't see "apple" anywhere in your desired output.

Comment: @Kevin I am not sure what you mean? Apple would be where it says "String" in the results section where I gave the demo. This is assigned with the line myValues[count]["Result"] = line in the code. The first json is just a data respresentation of the structure I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I add a few bits and pieces I can get this code to run:

```
count = 0
myValues = []
with open('myTextFile.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()
        d = {"IndvidualID":count, "Result":line}
        myValues.append(d)
        count = count + 1

TEST_SUITE_ID = 1
data = {"Name": "Demo",
       "Info": [{
          "MainID":TEST_SUITE_ID,
          "Values":myValues
       }]}
```

Output:

```
{'Name': 'Demo', 'Info': [{'MainID': 1, 
      'Values': [{'IndvidualID': 0, 'Result': 'apples'}, {'IndvidualID': 1, 'Result': 'another apples'}]
}]}
```

**Note:**

I have defined `myValues` as an empty `list`. I iterate over the file to read all lines and I create a new `dict` for each line, appending to `myValues` each time. Finally I create the whole `data` object with `myValues` embedded inside.

To get the above output I actually substituted: `f = ['apples','another apples']` for the open file, but I'm sure an actual file would work.

Comment: Thanks. Ya objects inside a list does it. Helps a lot :)